# Length of a composition series of a module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules

If $A=\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{(x,y)}$, then  what is the length of $A$-module

$$A/(x^3-x^2y^2+y^{100},x^3-y^{999})\ ?$$

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Using the "basis" command in *Macaulay2* yields the number 2997.